# Map touch display of the same type with xinput - which is which

Tags: linux, usb, xinput, touch

on my Linux box I have 2 DELL touch display of the exact same type. One is connected on  HDMI-2, the other on DP-1. To map the touch display I use

```
sudo xinput --map-to-output _ID1_ HDMI-2
sudo xinput --map-to-output _ID2_ DP-2
```

problem is every time I disconnect and reconnect the USB of touch device the ID changes...typically it inverts between *ID1* and *ID2* thus inverting touch on the two display. I need a way to be sure of the ID assigned to each monitor. Is there a way to track some property unique to the monitor to recognize them ?
Thanks

Lorenzo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you always use the same usb socket for a touchscreen, you might be able to convert the id used by xinput for a device to the fixed "path" of the device on the usb bus. Use `xinput list` to find the 2 ids of the touchscreens by name. Then use `xinput list-props` on each id and look for the Device Node, eg:

```
$ xinput list-props 12 | grep 'Device Node'
        Device Node (282):      "/dev/input/event6"
```

Then use `udevadm info` on that path `/dev/input/event6` and look for the DEVPATH or some line that is different between the 2 touchscreens and does not change, eg:

```
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.4/2-1.4.3/2-1.4.3:1.0/0003:1111:9999.0005/input/input6/event6
```

This path shows where on the bus the events come from. Just some part, such as `2-1.4.3` should be unique enough to identify the usb socket.
(If you are lucky, the touchscreens might have some unique serial number that could be shown in this output).
Here's a few lines of bash to experiment with:

```bash
name='The Touchscreen Name'
ids=$(xinput --list |awk -Fid= "/$name/"'{print $2+0}')
for id in $ids
do event=$(xinput list-props "$id" | awk -F'"' '/Device Node/{print $2}')
   path=$(udevadm info "$event" | 
          awk -F/ '/DEVPATH=/{printf "%s %s %s\n",$7,$8,$9}')
   echo "$id  $path"
done
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your code, it solved my problem. Actually it is not the way I was planning to do it, but it works OK. Thanks again !